# Performance that is equal to or better than the others

Tags: single-word-requests

When we compare performance between individuals, we can describe a situation in which an individual performed better than all others by saying that individual *outperformed* the others.

My question is:

Is there a similarly succinct way to describe a situation in which an individual performed better than *or equal to* the best among the other individuals (e.g. 1st place or tied for first)?

Comment: **Excellence**?

Comment: How about 'matched'?

Comment: @Řídící That usually means being equal, not better or worse.

Comment: I don't think there's a single word for this.

Comment: We usually just say "tied for first"

Comment: @Barmar is there anything shorter than "first or tied for first" or "better than or equal to the best"? Is there something like "outperform or equiperform"?

Comment: @Bitwise Not really. Maybe something like co-winners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not used in common parlance, but in medical and health research, the term 'noninferior' is used to describe interventions that are at least as good as a comparison intervention. However, it's not used to describe the performance of humans, as far as I know.